# Prototypal inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I've been watching Douglas Crockford's talks at YUI Theater, and I have a question about JavaScript inheritance...

Douglas gives this example to show that "Hoozit" inherits from "Gizmo":

```
function Hoozit(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
Hoozit.prototype = new Gizmo();
Hoozit.prototype.test = function (id) {
    return this.id === id;
};
```

Why does he write `Hoozit.prototype = new Gizmo()` instead of `Hoozit.prototype = Gizmo.prototype`?

Is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is that using `Hoozit.prototype = Gizmo.prototype` would mean that modifying Hoozit's prototype object would also modify objects of type Gizmo, which is not expected behavior.

`Hoozit.prototype = new Gizmo()` inherits from Gizmo, and then leaves Gizmo alone.

Comment: But you can use some indirection (parasitic inheritance) if you want to avoid calling the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers address this, but if you DO want to inherit the prototype, you can use some parasitic magic:

```
Object.prototype.inherit = function(p) {
    NewObj = function(){};
    NewObj.prototype = p;
    return new NewObj(); 
};

// Paraphrasing of Nicholas Zakas's Prototype Inheritance helper
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType) {
    var prototype = Object.inherit(superType.prototype);
    prototype.constructor = subType;
    subType.prototype = prototype;
};
```

Now you can replace the:

```
Hoozit.prototype = new Gizmo();
```

with

```
inheritPrototype(Hoozit, Gizmo);
```

It might not be worth the trouble unless you have a real big Gizmo constructor (the only win in my suggestion is that you don't have to call Gizmo's constructor to hook up the prototype). I have examples of many of these types of patterns in *[TDD JavaScript Examples](http://github.com/roblevintennis/Testing-and-Debugging-JavaScript)*.

Answer (score 2):

If he writes Hoozit.prototype = Gizmo.prototype any modfication he makes later to the prototype of Hoozit will be reflected in the prototype of Gizmo.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Triptych's answer: Hoozit instances will also inherit all instance properties of Gizmo, not only the ones defined in the prototype; eg:

```
function Gizmo() {
    this.foo = 'bar'; // foo is visible in every Hoozit instance
}
```